# move uploaded file to non-webroot php : permission denied

Tags: php, file-upload, copy

So I want to move a file after upload to a local path (say /proj/XXX/sharing)

I have given a permission of 777 to this directory, and the owner/group for this dir is also www/www (php user)

```
sudo chmod -R 777 sharing/
[user@localhost]$ sudo -u www mkdir /proj/XXX/sharing/dd
mkdir: /proj/XXX/sharing/dd: Permission denied
```

output of ls -l :

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 www      www           512 Oct 22 15:48 sharing
```

Still PHP complains about being denied permission when I try to either do mkdir, rename or a cp from /tmp to this folder.

Any ideas as to what might be the cuplrit?

Comment: /tmp ? drwxrwxrwt  11 root  wheel        1024 Oct 22 19:12 tmp

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /proj/XXX
```

please ref [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/wp-upgrade-cant-create-directory-even-though-perms-are-777)

Comment: can't do that, I don't want to make every folder in XXX world readable and writable :(